# How to modify crc-32 to crc-32/mpeg-2

Tags: c++, checksum, crc, crc32

I am trying to code a function to match CRC 32 output from a device to the actual CRC-32 sum that I calculate. Following is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h> 
#define CRC32_POLYNOMIAL 0xEDB88320
using namespace std;
unsigned int crc32b(unsigned char *message,size_t l)
{
   int i, j;
   unsigned int byte, crc, mask;

   i = 0;
   crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   while (i<l) {
      byte = message[i];            // Get next byte.
      crc = crc ^ byte;
      for (j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {    // Do eight times.
         mask = -(crc & 1);
         crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (0xEDB88320 & mask);
      }
      i = i + 1;
   }
   return ~crc;
}
int main()
{
    unsigned char Buff[] = {0x91,0xFF,0xFC,0xEA,0xFF,0xFF,0x70,0xFF,0xFD,0x87,0x00,0xFF,0xF9,0x1B,0xFF,0xF3,0x4E,0x00,0xFB,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x01,0xFB};
    unsigned long CRC =  crc32b((unsigned char *)Buff,24);
    cout << hex << CRC <<endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the 32 bit CRC output of following payload:

> 91FFFCEAFFFF70FFFD8700FFF91BFFF34E00FB00000201FB

as `1980AC80`. However the device is giving the checksum as `8059143D`.

Upon further inspection using online CRC calculators I found that the device is sending out CRC-32/MPEG-2 checksum value. (Can be verified [here](https://crccalc.com/)). I have browsed multiple sites but did not find any straight forward implementation of CRC32/MPEG2 which I can integrate in my code. Can anyone help?

Comment: A  little googling found this https://gist.github.com/Miliox/b86b60b9755faf3bd7cf  which you should be able to mold to your purpose. No license is mentioned though.

Comment: Yes works well. But I needed something without the need to store a precomputed table as this is for an embedded application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the crcalc web page, crc32/mpeg2 uses a left shifting (not reflected) CRC along with the CRC polynomial 0x104C11DB7 and initial CRC value of 0xFFFFFFFF, and not post complemented:

```
unsigned int crc32b(unsigned char *message, size_t l)
{
   size_t i, j;
   unsigned int crc, msb;

   crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
   for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      // xor next byte to upper bits of crc
      crc ^= (((unsigned int)message[i])<<24);
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {    // Do eight times.
            msb = crc>>31;
            crc <<= 1;
            crc ^= (0 - msb) & 0x04C11DB7;
      }
   }
   return crc;         // don't complement crc on output
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Nicely done! It produces the same results as in here: https://crccalc.com/.

Comment: FYI: [GarryS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6539631) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035330/12695027) (I assume they used an Answer since they cannot comment) that "Accepted response is good. But the polynomial mentioned is wrong, Please correct it from 0x104C11DB7 to 0x04C11DB7"

Comment: @Scratte - the short hand form of the polynomial is 0x104C11DB7, the software implementation doesn't use the most significant bit (x^32), so it xor's with 0x04C11DB7.